# Initial state type in Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using Redux Toolkit and trying two different approaches to set the initial state - assigning a primitive value and an object. In both cases the initial value should be typed as `number | null`. If I declare `initialState` as a primitive value, I get a type error when I update the state. However, if I declare `initialState` as an object, I get no error. Can you please explain what the problem is?

Implementation with an error:

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

type InitialState = number | null;

const initialState: InitialState = null;

const SelectedTestSlice = createSlice({
  name: "Test",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    selectTest: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      state = action.payload; // <-- Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'null'
    },
  },
});

export const { selectTest } = selectedTestSlice.actions;
export default selectedTestSlice.reducer;
```

Implementation without an error:

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

type InitialState = {
    test: number | null;
};

const initialState: InitialState = {
    test: null,
};

const SelectedTestSlice = createSlice({
  name: "Test",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    selectTest: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      state.test = action.payload; // <-- No error
    },
  },
});

export const { selectTest } = selectedTestSlice.actions;
export default selectedTestSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: This is typescript being smart and you not typing `createSlice`. You have told it that `type InitialState = number | null;` You then create a constant of this type and set it to null: `const initialState: InitialState = null;`. This constant can only ever be `null` and typescript sees it as such. With the object being the constant the properties are free to change so typescript doesn't see this as locked to null. [See This](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgS2AghgGwMrBcaBeKOAVwFsAjCAJygB9Ci00BuAKBYGMB7OAZ2CgSJk6LDggAuWENSZsuKAWKNWHbnygATImFHyCgpDN0QmQA) check `dupState`

Comment: It's also often helpful to use certain values like zero to express the empty or initial state and stay within the same primitive (number). Works for things like "number of shopping cart items", but not for everything of course. This avoids issues like yours.